# Sticky Euro cylinder lock

Tags: lock

I have a Euro cylinder lock like below and it has got rather sticky - the key turn isn't as smooth as other locks.

[image]

Does anyone know how to lubricate it to make it less sticky? I've read about graphite powder for other lock types, but are they suitable for Euro cylinder locks as well?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Far from being an expert, here is my personal experience: silicon dry spray alone inside the cylinder, and  WD40 on the sliding mechanism.

As for the cylinder, I had been advised to use  graphite dust or silicon dry spray (non-greasy) by different key makers. I first used graphite dust, but it tended to agglomerate, so I finally used air duster cleaning to remove graphite dust and grease employed by former owners, during a hot day so that the old graphite & grease mix was liquid enough to pour out of the lock.

One important lesson I learned to never leave keys plugged inside the lock, because it prematurely ages the mechanisms.

Additional source: [LocksOnline : help  maintain  locks](https://www.locksonline.co.uk/community/locksonline-top-tips-lubricating-locks.html)

Comment: WD40 is a primarily a Water Displacement (WD) product. I use it when storing steel tools in my garage to stave off corrosion. Its lubricating properties are unusually temporary and, after a while, the volatile lubricants can evaporate leaving a gummy/sticky residue. I'd use a light oil or silicone lubriucant spray on locks. This seems to be a contentious subject though.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, a key maker even told me to use WD40 when others prohibited it firmly. I uses it on another lock, despite the caveats, because the others did not work. I do have to regularly update the treatment, until I change the lock. Thx for the WD origin I was not aware of